# How to replace ramdisk inside boot.img

Tags: android

I 'm doing like in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69954/how-to-unpack-and-edit-boot-img-for-rom-porting , trying to repalce a ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk.gz inside a boot.img .
My goal is to boot my custom rom using the stock kernel .
However the device just restart in recovery mode.
It is possible to just replace boot.img-ramdisk.gz inside a boot.img ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works good, but I had to get the dt from my kernel too .